# Cinemachine: Lock rotation and smooth movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I'm trying to figure out Cinemachine to create some kind of Top view perspective. I managed to find the setting to make sure the camera keeps it's rotation, and follows the player. My issue now is that little extra movement that happens when the player is moving. Is there a way for me to get rid of it, so that my camera stays still?

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT8mS.gif)

[Camera Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfK9n.png)

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF4Vx.gif)

Edit:
[Edit after comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyF2r.gif)
[Camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLc8p.png)

Comment: remove damping from your camera and see if your problem still exists

Comment: It did stop the extra movement, but now the camera rotates again around the player.

Comment: can you post it?

Comment: Just edited the main post

Answer (score 1):

You can set Body type to transposer and Binding Mode to world space:

[image: Answer]

Comment: Is this answer correct?

Comment: Yes It is! Thank you very much! Just had to tweak the follow offset and it's perfect! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the aim setting to Do Nothing? If you leave it to Hard look at it will always keep your player at the center of the camera.

You can read the documentation here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6/manual/CinemachineVirtualCameraAim.html

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I want the camera to follow the player, while keeping the same point of view.